# Can the WKB approximation be used to get eigenenergies for negative potential 'barriers'?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

I recently took a course that discussed the WKB approximation for linear potential. In class and in the exercises we only looked at pretty simple potentials that are just a constant times |x|. What I tried to do I see if I could solve a potential like:

$$V(x)=\begin{cases}
0& x<-a \\
  -a+|x|&  -a\leq x\leq a\\ 
0 & x > a.
\end{cases}$$

Which looks like (sorry for my poor paint skills):

[image]

Now, the problem I come up with is that if you simply solve the WKB solution for the eigenenergies with this potential the result is not very illuminating as $E_n$ can not be expressed on its own. What I tried to do after is to simply do a transformation of the potential and energy like: $V'(x) \rightarrow V(x) + a $ and $E'_n \rightarrow E_n + a$. After solving for $E'_n$ you could then simply reverse the transformation which will result in $$E_n = A(n+\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{2}{3}} - a.$$ I am just not entirely sure that this is allowed as it seems 'cheaty' to me. This makes me question whether the WKB approximation is valid for all linear potential.

So, is it allowed to do such a transformation without loss of generality? And if not, are the eigenenergies solveable with the WKB approximation of this potential in such a form that $E_n$ can be expressed on its own?

Comment: WKB should work just fine for this potential. In fact, it should work *really well* for this potential, provided the well is relatively deep so that there are a number of bound states.  It won't work that well if there are only a few bound states in the potential well.

Comment: Up to unit issues (you're setting an energy equal to something that has length; I would multiply your expression for $V(x)$ by $V_0/a$, making $V_0$ the depth of the well) and a missing factor of $\hbar$ and maybe $\pi$, this seems fine. I got an expression $\frac{(3 \pi )^{2/3} (2 n+1)^{2/3} V_0^{2/3} \hbar ^{2/3}}{4 a^{2/3}}-V_0$. Although, I don't understand what you meant by "shifting"; I just computed $\int\sqrt{p(x)}$ as usual.

Comment: You make a good point about the units. Interesting that you got to a proper result. How did you choose your bounds on the integral? I simply took $\int_{-a}^{a} \sqrt{\rho(|x|)} \,dx $ = $2\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{\rho(x)} \,dx $. If that is not the problem then I'll have to check my work tomorrow. But I dont see how an integral of the form: $\int_{-a}^{a} \sqrt{2m(E+\frac{V_0}{a}-|x|)}$ has a result where there is no $(\frac{V_0}{a}-E_n)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ (not entirely sure about the exact form) term which implies that $E_n$ can't be simply written as a result like yours.

Comment: To use WKB to get bound states, you are supposed to integrate between the two classical turning points corresponding to the energy E.  The quantization condition for two "soft" boundaries is $\frac{1}{\hbar}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{E-V(x)}dx = (n+\frac{1}{2})\pi$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the turning points, i.e., the points where $E=V(x)$.

Comment: I got it, thank you!